# mvn install of Spring Security OAuth2 fails during test Phase

Tags: maven, oauth, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I tried to install and run the samples as per the "Getting started" section of the Spring OAuth project on github: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth. I tried it different ways and always run into the same errors during the maven test phase when running `mvn install -P bootstrap`

Here are some of the variants I tried:

- Downloaded v.2.0.9-SNAPSHOT with Eclipse egit

  - changed to tagged release v2.0.8
  - changed to tagged release v2.0.7
  - changed to tagged release v2.0.6
- Downloaded the 2.0.9-SNAPSHOT from master as a zip
- Downloaded 2.0.8 release version as a zip
- cleared the local maven repository (in fact referenced a blank dir in the maven settings.xml)
- used to different maven versions (3.0.5 and 3.3.3)
- used three different JDKs

The outcome of the test phase was always this:

```
Results :

Tests in error:
  testExpiringRefreshToken(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)
  testExpiringRefreshToken(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)
  testExpiringAccessToken(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)
  testExpiringAccessToken(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)
  testStoreRefreshToken(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)
  testStoreRefreshToken(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)
  testRetrieveAccessToken(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)
  testRetrieveAccessToken(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)
  testReadingRefreshTokenForTokenThatDoesNotExist(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)
  testReadingRefreshTokenForTokenThatDoesNotExist(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)
  testFindAccessTokensByClientId(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)
  testFindAccessTokensByClientId(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)
  testFindAccessTokensByClientIdAndUserName(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)
  testFindAccessTokensByClientIdAndUserName(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)
  testStoreAccessToken(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)
  testStoreAccessToken(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)
  testRemovedTokenCannotBeFoundByUsername(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)
  testRemovedTokenCannotBeFoundByUsername(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)
  testReadingAccessTokenForTokenThatDoesNotExist(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)
  testReadingAccessTokenForTokenThatDoesNotExist(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)
  testRemoveRefreshToken(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)
  testRemoveRefreshToken(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)
  testReadingAuthenticationForTokenThatDoesNotExist(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)
  testReadingAuthenticationForTokenThatDoesNotExist(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)
  testStoreAccessTokenTwice(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)
  testStoreAccessTokenTwice(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)
  testRefreshTokenIsNotStoredDuringAccessToken(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)
  testRefreshTokenIsNotStoredDuringAccessToken(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)
  testGetAccessTokenForDeletedUser(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)
  testGetAccessTokenForDeletedUser(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)

Tests run: 610, Failures: 0, Errors: 30, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] OAuth for Spring Security .......................... SUCCESS [  2.044 s]
[INFO] OAuth 1(a) for Spring Security ..................... SUCCESS [ 20.215 s]
[INFO] OAuth2 for Spring Security ......................... FAILURE [ 29.350 s]
[INFO] spring-oauth2-tests ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] spring-oauth2-tests-common ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] spring-oauth2-tests-vanilla ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] spring-oauth2-tests-mappings ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] spring-oauth2-tests-form ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] spring-oauth2-tests-jwt ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] spring-oauth2-tests-approval ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] spring-oauth2-tests-jdbc ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] spring-oauth-tests-custom-grant .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] spring-oauth2-tests-multi .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] spring-oauth2-tests-client ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] spring-oauth2-tests-resource ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] spring-oauth2-tests-custom-authentication .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] spring-oauth2-tests-xml ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] spring-oauth2-tests-xml-common ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] spring-oauth2-tests-xml-vanilla .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] spring-oauth2-tests-xml-mappings ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] spring-oauth2-tests-xml-form ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] spring-oauth2-tests-xml-jwt ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] spring-oauth2-tests-xml-approval ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] spring-oauth2-tests-xml-jdbc ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] spring-oauth2-tests-xml-client ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] OAuth for Spring Security - Integration Tests ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] OAuth for Spring Security - Sparklr (OAuth 1 Provider Example) SKIPPED
[INFO] OAuth for Spring Security - Tonr (OAuth 1 Consumer Example) SKIPPED
[INFO] OAuth for Spring Security - Sparklr2 (OAuth 2 Provider Example) SKIPPED
[INFO] OAuth for Spring Security - Tonr2 (OAuth 2 Client Example) SKIPPED
[INFO] OAuth for Spring Security - Samples ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 52.860 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-12-03T16:53:58+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 59M/172M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project spring-security-oauth2: There are test failures.
[...]
```

Here are some of the exceptions I encountered during the tests:

```
[...]
testExpiringRefreshToken(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)  Time elapsed: 0.008 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
    at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:2984)
    at redis.embedded.RedisServer.extractExecutableFromJar(RedisServer.java:85)
    at redis.embedded.RedisServer.<init>(RedisServer.java:69)
    at redis.embedded.RedisServer.<init>(RedisServer.java:63)
    at redis.embedded.RedisServer.<init>(RedisServer.java:55)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests.setup(RedisTokenStoreTests.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)

testExpiringRefreshToken(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)  Time elapsed: 0.008 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests.tearDown(RedisTokenStoreTests.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:33)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)

testExpiringAccessToken(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
    at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:2984)
    at redis.embedded.RedisServer.extractExecutableFromJar(RedisServer.java:85)
    at redis.embedded.RedisServer.<init>(RedisServer.java:69)
    at redis.embedded.RedisServer.<init>(RedisServer.java:63)
    at redis.embedded.RedisServer.<init>(RedisServer.java:55)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStoreTests.setup(RedisTokenStoreTests.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
[...]
```

Since obviously noone else is encountering this behaviour I must do something really wrong but I dont have a clue what it could be.

Hoping for help,
 Björn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is actually an issue with embedded Redis on your operating system (OS). We tried to leverage embedded Redis in Spring Session, but it caused to many problems for various OS's. See [spring-session/issues/121](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/121#issuecomment-124653443)

In short, I think this is a bug with the test.

Comment: Rob has also provided some more details on the project page on github: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/650 Maybe this is also helpful to others.